# Draw something once in android canvas

Tags: java, android, graphics

I am creating chess game and I need to draw chess board once, but also I should redraw figures each time players makes his move.

So I should put figure drawing in method `onDraw()` and call `invalidate()` each time I need to, but where can I draw game board once and it won't be redrawn each time I call `invalidate()`? If I put everything in `onDraw()` method my gameboard redraws each time I call `invalidate()`.

Comment: Why not draw the chessboard in a separate view which lies below your figures?

Comment: @Risch As I understand the way views are working - activity has only one view and I can't attach more views to one activity. Of course I can create one static activity which will show game board and put another on top of it, but i don't think that will work properly, and i think there must be a way to do it correctly

Comment: Ah, well the activity has one content view witch is set with the method setContentView in the onCreate method of your activity. This content view is typically a ViewGroup which my contain several child views. If you read through [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html) you should get a better understanding of how views and layouts work in android. I'd recommend trying to use a FrameLayout with two views, the board view and the view that draws your figures. You are not forced to use XML for declaring it but I would suggest that you do :)

Comment: @Risch, thanks, and one more question, can I create one view using XML and in it create two views - first view will be realised using XML and second will be realised in java code? Can i somehow say to parent XML that one view should be realised with block of code?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, in short yes, what you could do is acquire the layout using findViewById(int idRes) to get a reference to the layout view, cast it to the correct layout and then add it using viewGroup.addView(View view).

ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.idOfLayout);
vg.addView(viewCreatedInCode);